# Sitemaps XML format: should new articles be in the beginning of the file?

Tags: html, xml, sitemap

Should new articles in sitemap.xml be in the beginning of the file or the end?
Didn't find this information on http://www.sitemaps.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sitemap is not an RSS feed, where new items can be distinguished purely from their properties. A sitemap is just what it says. There is nothing to stop you choosing your own order but you cannot know how a client program will process the data.